# Iterate on page of returning execute_values

Tags: psycopg2

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html

psycopg2.extras.execute_values has a parameters `page_size`. 
I'm doing an `INSERT INTO... ON CONFLICT...` with `RETURNING ID`.

The problem is that the `cursor.fetchall()` give me back only the last "page", that is, 100 ids (default of `page_size`).

Without modifying `page_size` parameters, is it possible to iterate over the results, to get the total number of rows updated ?

Answer (score 1):

The best and shortest answer would be using `fetch = True` in parameter as stated in [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_values#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)

```
all_ids = psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, query, data, template=None, page_size=10000, fetch=True)
# all_ids will return all affected rows with array like this [  [1], [2], [3] .... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  I work around this issue by batching my calls to execute_values().  I'll set my_page_size=1000, then iterate over my values, filling argslist until i have my_page_size items.  Then I'll call execute_values(cur, sql, argslist, page_size=my_page_size).  And iterate over cur to get those ids.

Answer (score 0):

> Without modifying `page_size` parameters, is it possible to iterate over
> the results, to get the total number of rows updated ?

Yes.

```py
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = """
        WITH
            items (eggs) AS (VALUES %s), 
            inserted AS (
                INSERT INTO spam (eggs)
                SELECT eggs FROM items
                ON CONFLICT (eggs) DO NOTHING
                RETURNING id
            )
        SELECT id FROM spam
        WHERE eggs IN (SELECT eggs FROM items)
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM inserted
    """
    eggs = (('egg_{}'.format(i % 666),) for i in range(10_000))
    ids = psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, query, argslist=eggs, fetch=True)
    # Do whatever with `ids`. `len(ids)` I suppose?
finally:
    if connection:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

I overkilled query on purpose to address some gotchas:

- `WITH items (eggs) AS (VALUES %s)` is done to be able to use `argslist` in two places at once;
- `RETURNING` with `ON CONFLICT` will return only `id`s which were actually inserted, conflicting ones are omitted from `INSERT`' direct results. To solve that all this `SELECT ... WHERE ... UNION SELECT` mumbo jumbo is done;
- to get all values which you asked for: `ids = psycopg2.extras.execute_values(..., fetch=True)`.

A horrible interface oddity considering that all other cases are done like

```py
cur.execute(...)  # or other kind of `execute`
rows = cur.fetchall()  # or other kind of `fetch`
```

So if you want only the number of inserted rows then do

```py
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = """
        INSERT INTO spam (eggs)
        VALUES %s
        ON CONFLICT (eggs) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id
    """
    eggs = (('egg_{}'.format(i % 666),) for i in range(10_000))
    ids = psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, query, argslist=eggs, fetch=True)
    print(len(ids)
finally:
    if connection:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```